# Multiple columns in "UIPickerView"

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

In my project is added Days and month
How to add two fields in (date and time) UIPickerView. 
In My code is

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource{
    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
@IBOutlet var dateTextfield:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel:UILabel!
 var pickerDaysYear = [["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"],["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]];

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.pickerview.delegate = self

}
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
           return self.pickerDaysYear[component].count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if(component == 0)
        {
            return self.pickerDaysYear[component][row]
        }
        else
        {
            return self.pickerDaysYear[component][row]
        }
        
//        return pickerDaysYear[component][row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let days =  pickerDaysYear[0][pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        let month = pickerDaysYear[1][pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
        dateTextfield.text = days + " " + month
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(false)
    }
```

Output is:

[image missing]

And i expected this output:

[image]

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: its display only one field(months)

Comment: But i expected output is added two fields (days and months) in pickerView

Comment: can you please add the image of the current status ?

Comment: nice that you have an answer - but to understand you problem and your question and then the answer it would be nice to see the image for "the current output is:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet var dateTextfield:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel:UILabel!
    let datePicker = UIPickerView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dateTextfield.delegate = self

        self.datePicker.dataSource = self
        self.datePicker.delegate = self

        self.dateTextfield.inputView = self.datePicker

        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonTapped))
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
        self.dateTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
func doneButtonTapped(){
        self.dateTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

//----------------   PickerView  delegate Method   --------------------------------//

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.pickerDaysmonth[component].count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return self.pickerDaysmonth[component][row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let days =  pickerDaysmonth[0][pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        let month = pickerDaysmonth[1][pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
        dateTextfield.text =   days + " " + month

    }
```

Assign the inputview for textfield in UIPickerView()

```
let datePicker = UIPickerView()

self.dateTextfield.inputView = self.datePicker
```

Assign the inputAccessoryView for textfield in toolBar

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    self.dateTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

It's Working fine

**The current Output is:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Function `numberOfComponents` and `numberOfRowsInComponent` are from data source, not delegate.

So you need to add this line to your `viewDidLoad`:

`self.pickerview.delegate = self`

Comment: @RamprasathS Please mark it as correct if it fix your problem, or let me know if something else goes wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is looking for the OBJC calls for component inside the protocol calls

- for number of rows use

  ```
   return [yourArrayName[component] count];
  ```
- for title for row use

  ```
   return yourArrayName[component][row];
  ```

Comment: This can be used in Swift too! It solved my problem!